# How to register service in Consul without address declaration

Tags: java, microservices, service-discovery, consul

Using Consul, I want a service to register itself with the Consul Agent, using the HTTP endpoint `/v1/agent/service/register`. The only problem is that the service may bind to different IP addresses (1st instance 10.0.0.1, 2nd 10.0.0.2, etc) and I want Consul to set the address automatically basing on the IP address of the request.

For example,

"Service instance 1 (10.0.0.1)" sends `{name:'svs', id:'svs-01'}` to `/v1/agent/service/register` and Consul registers it as `{name:'svs', id:'svs-01', Address: 10.0.0.1}`

"Service instance 2 (10.0.0.2)" sends `{name:'svs', id:'svs-02'}` to `/v1/agent/service/register` and Consul registers it as `{name:'svs', id:'svs-02', Address: 10.0.0.2}`

According to [Consul Agent Service Documentation](https://consul.io/docs/agent/http/agent.html#agent_service_register) if the Address field is missing in service register query, the Address will default to that of the agent if not provided. But it is not what I need.

I've tried to detect service's ip address at runtime but it may have several network interfaces and it's hard to distinguish them.

Comment: Am I correct in my assumption that you do these HTTP requests to a consul master instead of to the local consul agent running on the server that is hosting the service?

Comment: @Tborra yes. I'm using this api wrapper github.com/Ecwid/consul-api to talk with master server

Answer (score 1):

You need to register your service from the machines which run them. Consul is really designed in doing that. You need to use the agent rather than the HTTP API.

By the way, if you still want to register that remote service from a Consul server directly, you will need to do extra work in order to detect on which IP it is running and submit a already correct json config.
Know that health checks don't work for remote service as those health checks are intended to be run locally.

Check the answer of one Consul dev here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/consul-tool/r4ZY97PE7BY/9QTRd3EsBgAJ

> The Catalog API is used by the agents to report the state of their
>   services and checks to the Consul servers. It's very unusual to talk
>   to the Catalog API directly, and Consul doesn't really support running
>   checks without a Consul agent. If you run an agent on a node you can
>   register services and checks for that node using the Agent API by
>   doing a curl -X PUT with a body like this:
>
> https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/http/agent.html#agent_service_register
>
> It's also possible to define health checks in the agent's
>   configuration files. The agent runs the checks and manages keeping the
>   catalog up to date with the servers as the health status changes using
>   an internal version of the Catalog API.
>
> If you called this Agent API on one of your Consul servers it's
>   possible to have them run checks as well, but that's an unusual
>   configuration to use if it's going to be checking the health of a
>   service on another node. By running an agent on each node you get some
>   basic "node is reachable" checking for free by Consul itself, and you
>   keep the knowledge of the services and checks out at the edges where
>   they are being run (the Catalog API lets the Consul servers answer
>   questions across your whole fleet, but in Consul the agents are the
>   source of truth and keep the catalog up to date to match what's going
>   on).

Comment: `You need to register your service from the machines which run them.` - it's oblivious :) That is how I test Consul now: consul agent -server locally, than my java application using https://github.com/Ecwid/consul-api to register itself.

Comment: I do not use Catalog API and I mentioned it in my question